# Validate ReCapatcha in form?

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have a registration form on my website where i put ReCapatcha on the registration form. I am trying to change it to server side validation as seen bellow but i am only ending up with "Captcha confirmation is invalid" whenever i try to submit the form with this code, Anyone know why ?

**HEADER**

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

**PHP**

```
$secretKey = "MYSECRETKEY";
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

if (!$captcha) {
    //no captacha
   exit;
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secretKey . "&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $ip);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);

if (intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
    setError(t("invalid_captcha", "Captcha confirmation is invalid."));
} else {
   //Valid captcha
}
```

**HTML**

In my `<form method="post"></form>` in the html par i have this

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add script in your code:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

To get/check captcha:

```
$secretKey = "your secret key";
$captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

if (!$captcha) {
   //no captcha
   exit;
}

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $secretKey . "&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $ip);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);

if (intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
   //Invalid captcha
} else {
   //Valid captcha
}
```

> (Assuming you have registered on google captcha)

Inspect your html and check if key is here:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>"></div>
```

Please comment if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi, thank you! i have update my main post with exactly how my code looks right now. I still get an invalid captacha response. I tried to remove the if (!$captcha) { part just to test and i still get an invalid captacha response. I inspected the souce when the page loaded and my Site_Key is visible. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your keys once again, as above code is working for me.